# How to send operational log data from Azure IoT Edge runtime device?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

We have an Edge device running Azure IoT Edge Runtime. The device is sending telemetry data from sensors to IoT Hub but all operational logging is done to logs on the device.

What is the recommended way to send operational log data, i.e. not the actual sensor data, from an edge device? Should we send them to their own topic in IoT Hub or is there some dedicated method?

Answer (score 2):

IoT Edge supports native retrieval of module logs and upload to Azure Blob Storage as of Version 1.0.8 as an experimental feature. To enable it, the following environment variables need to be set for the edgeAgent (make note of the double underscores):

```
ExperimentalFeatures__Enabled=true
ExperimentalFeatures__EnableUploadLogs=true
```

Refer [here](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/master/doc/built-in-logs-pull.md) for more details.

Also, there are some custom solutions like this [one](https://github.com/veyalla/logspout-loganalytics), that work with Log Analytics workspace, but the problem is that you do not have any guarantee for the maintenance.

And the third option would be, your own custom implementation, potentially by leveraging Azure blob storage module, and that way you can store whatever you want and have a local blob store to be synced in a secured way with the remote blob storage acc.